# How to search Shopify products using title and vendor

Tags: search, shopify

I am using the Shopify Storefront search to generate JSON: http://wiki.shopify.com/Storefront_search

Our client has a very large catalogue and we need to be able to search on the product title and product vendor fields but **exclude** the product body field.

Here is an example of the problem:

Say we have a products called "Galaxy S4" and "Galaxy S3" with vendor "Samsung" and the body text for the S4 starts "Improving on the wildly popular Galaxy S3" we will get the following search results:

**myshopify.com/search?q=samsung galaxy s3&type=product&view=json**
(searches all product fields for all the words in "samsung galaxy s3")

- "Galaxy S3"
- "Galaxy S4"

As the phrase "Galaxy S3" appears in the S4 body text it is listed in the search results -not ideal.

**myshopify.com/search?q=title:samsung galaxy s3 OR vendor:samsung galaxy s3&type=product&view=json**
(searches title field OR vendor field for all the words in "samsung galaxy s3" - this means that unless all of the words appear in either field no results are returned.)

- No results

So the outcome we'd like is that is as long as each word in the search term appears in either the title OR the vendor the item is listed.

I hope this makes sense, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach I have taken. I'm using Javascript to take the search query and turn it into a title OR vendor AND title OR vendor string:

```
var words = search_query.split(" ");
var search_string = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
  if(words[i].length>0){
    if(i > 0){
      search_string += ' AND ';
    }
    search_string += 'title:'+words[i]+' OR vendor:'+words[i];
  }
}
```

Using the example above this gives the following string:
**myshopify.com/search?q=title:samsung OR vendor:samsung AND title:galaxy OR vendor:galaxy AND title:s3 OR vendor:s3&type=product&view=json**

Which returns the desired search results.

**Note:**
Adding an asterisk to each side of the search words will also return partial word matches. i.e.:

```
search_string += 'title:*'+words[i]+'* OR vendor:*'+words[i]+'*';
```

Will make "samsun" match "samsung"

Comment: If you're wondering what view=json does with Shopify, this might clear things up.

Basically, view=thing makes Shopify load a different template liquid file. So if you put view=json, you need to make a search.json.liquid file and have it output JSON like `{% layout none %}{{ search.results | json }}` 
You can also use this to load alternate templates from a query param